# Compose variadic template argument by transforming them

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a simple situation which probably require a complex way to be solved but I'm unsure of it.

Basically I have this object which encapsulated a member function:

```
template<class T, typename R, typename... ARGS>
class MemberFunction
{
private:
  using function_type = R (T::*)(ARGS...);

  function_type function;

public:
  MemberFunction(function_type function) : function(function) { }

  void call(T* object, ARGS&&... args)
  {
    (object->*function)(args...);
  }   
};
```

This can be used easily

```
MemberFunction<Foo, int, int, int> function(&Foo::add)
Foo foo;
int res = function.call(&foo, 10,20)
```

The problem is that I would like to call it by passing through a custom environment which uses a stack of values to operate this method, this translates to the following code:

```
int arg2 = stack.pop().as<int>();
int arg1 = stack.pop().as<int>();
Foo* object = stack.pop().as<Foo*>();
int ret = function.call(object, arg1, arg2);
stack.push(Value(int));
```

This is easy to do directly in code but I'd like to find a way to encapsulate this behavior directly into `MemberFunction` class by exposing a single `void call(Stack& stack)` method which does the work for me to obtain something like:

```
MemberFunction<Foo, int, int, int> function(&Foo::add);
Stack stack;
stack.push(Value(new Foo());
stack.push(10);
stack.push(20);
function.call(stack);
assert(stack.pop().as<int>() == Foo{}.add(10,20));
```

But since I'm new to variadic templates I don't know how could I do in efficiently and elegantly.

#### EDIT: Adding specifics about Stack and StackValue

the stack I'm talking about is a wrapper around a `std::stack<StackValue>` which provides template methods to push and pop elements, something like

```
struct StackValue
{
  union
  {
    float fvalue;
    s32 ivalue;
    bool bvalue;
    FloatPair fpair;
    IntPair ipair;
    void* ptr;
  };

  template<typename T> T as();
  template<typename T> StackValue(T type);

  StackValue() { }
};

template<> inline StackValue::StackValue(float f) : fvalue(f) { }
template<> inline StackValue::StackValue(s32 i) : ivalue(i) { }
...

template<> inline float StackValue::as<float>() { return fvalue; }
template<> inline s32 StackValue::as<s32>() { return ivalue; }
...

class Stack
{
private:
  std::stack<StackValue> stack;

public:
  StackValue& peek() { return stack.top(); }
  StackValue pop() { StackValue v = stack.top(); stack.pop(); return v; }
  void push(StackValue value) { stack.push(value); }

  template<typename T> void pushValue(T value) { stack.push(StackValue(value)); }
  template<typename T> T popValue() {
      StackValue v = stack.top().as<T>();
      stack.pop();
      return v;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the function supposed to be called with all values from the stack? As in, the stack represents its own parameter pack in a way?

Comment: @AndyG: Yes, the Stack represent an execution environment which holds the object on which call the function and all the arguments, as well where the return value will be placed, I added a stub of the implementation to better clarify what I'm using behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're going to have to do this recursively in order to guarantee that we pop stuff in the right order:

```
void call(Stack& s) {
    call_impl(std::integral_constant<int, sizeof...(ARGS)>{}, s);
}
```

with:

```
template <int N, typename... StackVals>
void call_impl(std::integral_constant<int, N>, Stack& s, StackVals... vals) {
    call_impl(std::integral_constant<int, N-1>{}, s, s.pop(), vals...);
}

template <typename... StackVals
void call_impl(std::integral_constant<int, 0>,
               Stack& s,
               StackVals... vals)
{
    // now we have all the args
    T* object = s.pop().as<T*>();

    // so just call
    s.push(call(object, vals.as<Args>()...));
}
```

First, we `pop` off all of our arguments one by one, and we put the next `pop()`-ed one ahead of the other ones so far. Then, the key expression is:

```
vals.as<Args>()...
```

`vals` is a parameter pack of `StackValues` that we just built up, and `Args` is a parameter pack of arguments to the function. If we did things right, these two packs should be the same size (otherwise, this wouldn't compile). The expansion would expand both concurrently as:

```
val0.as<Arg0>, val1.as<Arg1>, val2.as<Arg2>, ...
```

which is exactly what we were looking for. The only other thing we needed was to pop off the `T*`, and present that as the first argument to `call()`.

---

Side-note, this signature:

```
void call(T* object, ARGS&&... args);
```

is incorrect. That takes a bunch of rvalue references. You either want to take `ARGS...` or make this a function template to do forwarding references. Also it should probably return `R`.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I see what you do here and it's quite elegant indeed. I imagined I had to build `StackValue` values through a recursive template but I didn't know some specific things like `sizeof...(ARGS)` which is necessary to know when to stop and `vals.as<ARGS>()` which actually calls a specialization for each variable in the parameter pack by using the respective type in the variadic template argument right? Just a side curiosity: how much overhead in final binary size does this create with -Os/-O2 assuming some hundreds of methods? Should I worry about it?

Comment: @Jack Don't worry about it until you have to worry about it - when you can determine that it's become a problem, *then* try to solve it.

Comment: that's usually the good thing to do but since I plan to embed this inside a large code base which wouldn't benefit from a relevant binary size bloat I was just wondering if the elegant and type-safe solution has a considerable cost or not. Just because spending too much effort to be forced to redesign it from scratches afterwards wouldn't be nice :)

Comment: @Jack Depends on the rest of your system. Can't really give you a good prediction.